# DragOver and DragLeave in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to create an element that users can hold their mouse over to slowly scroll the page down while they are dragging an element. This is necessary to support my Drag-&-Drop editor.

I'm detecting if the user hovers over the anchor and is dragging, and if so I start an `$interval` where I initiate the slow scroll. If the mouse leave the anchor, or the user stops dragging, the slow scroll should be cancelled, but it's not. Below is my code.

```
elem.on('dragover', mouseOver);

elem.on('dragleave', mouseLeave);
elem.on('dragend', mouseLeave);

var scroller = null;

function mouseOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    console.log('over');

    scroller = $interval(function () {
        if (!scrolledToBottom()) {
            $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
        }
    }, 10);

}

function mouseLeave(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    console.log('left');

    $interval.cancel(scroller);
    scroller = null;
}

function scrolledToBottom() {
    return ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == 
    $(document).height();
}
```

Even though the `console.log`'s fire just fine, the scroller never stops scrolling. I think this is because Angular cannot see inside the event as it's triggered and fails to apply the changes to the scroller. However, Angular has no `ngDragOver`, and I can only think of JQuery implementations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you even need custom scroll? Window scroll will happen automatically if you are dragging an element out of the viewport.

Comment: A sensible respone for anyone familiar with computers, but I'm afraid my users won't be. This also doesn't work for scrolling back up if the site has a fixed top-bar menu.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but then you should remember to take care of any other accessibility issues that you would introduce(if any). Anyways,  look at the answer that I've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have registered events like 
`elem.on('dragover', mouseOver)`, `elem.on('dragleave', mouseLeave)`and `elem.on('dragend', mouseLeave)` and as the [doc mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Drag_Events) that `During the operations, several event types are fired and some event types might be fired many times (for example the drag and dragover event types).`

For example your `dragover` event handler looks like:

```
function mouseOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    console.log('over');

    scroller = $interval(function () {
        if (!scrolledToBottom()) {
            $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
        }
    }, 10);

}
```

So, the above event handler will fire multiple times registering `$interval` multiple time and will loose reference to the old promise.

Fix that by using the following check:

```
var scroller  = null;
function mouseOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    console.log('over');

    if (scroller === null) {  // <-- This check will prevent multiple $interval registration.
        scroller = $interval(function () {
            if (!scrolledToBottom()) {
                $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
            }
        }, 10);
    }

}
```

I would remove the `elem.on('dragleave', mouseLeave)` event handler registration call as this event handler if registered will also be called as soon as you start the element drag. And thus cancelling the custom `scoll` logic.

Also, I would suggest changing your `dragend` event handler to make a check before cancelling the `$interval`, like(This is just for code clarity):

```
function mouseLeave(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (scroller !== null) {  // <-- Make a check before cancelling the 
        $interval.cancel(scroller);
        scroller = null;
    }

}
```

Here is an working example to try out:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('drag', function($interval) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        elem.on('dragover', mouseOver);
        elem.on('dragend', mouseLeave);

        var scroller = null;

        function mouseOver(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();

          if (scroller === null) {
            scroller = $interval(function() {
              if (!scrolledToBottom()) {
                $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
              }
            }, 10);
          }

        }

        function mouseLeave(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();

          if (scroller !== null) {
            $interval.cancel(scroller);
            scroller = null;
          }

        }

        function scrolledToBottom() {
          return ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) ==
            $(document).height();
        }
      }
    }

  });
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  height: 800px;
}

.container .drag {
  height: 300px;
}

.container .drag a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js "></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="drag">
      <a href="" drag>Drag Me</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This has everything I needed :)